# Is the following proposition true or false?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

The next proposition is in a Japanese algebra text written by a Japanese mathematician who is famous in algebraic geometry.

But the proof is obviously not correct.

Then, is the next proposition true or false?

> Let $k \subset k_1 \subset k_2$ be fields. If an element $\alpha\in k_2$ is algebraic over $k$, it is algebraic over $k_1$. If $\alpha$ has degree $n$ over $k$, its degree over $k_1$ divides $n$.

Comment: Of course the first part is true, because elements of $k$ are also elements of $k_1$, so $k[x] \subset k_1[x]$. Similarly, the second part is also true.

Comment: If $\alpha$ is a root of $p(x)\in k[x]$, and $k[x]\subseteq k_1[x]$ , $\alpha$ is algebraic over $k_1$ and the proposition is trivial. Perhaps the proof you are reading is not for this particular assertion?

Comment: What is the proof of the second part?

Comment: Do you know the Tower Law, Bolt? Its proof is just linear algebra.

Comment: His proof of the second part is here:
Let $f(x)$ be the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $k$. $f(x)$ is a polynomial in $k[x] \subset k_1[x]$.
Let $g(x)$ be the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $k_1$. Then $g(x)$ devides $f(x)$. So, $\deg g(x)$ devides $\deg f(x)$.

Comment: "Then $g(x)$ devides $f(x)$. So, $\deg g(x)$ devides $\deg f(x)$" is not  a correct proof.

Comment: I guess this proposition is not true, but I am a beginner of field theory, so I don't know  a counterexample.

Comment: @GerryMyerson If my answer is correct, the result is not true and the tower law doesn't directly apply.

Comment: 6005, Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

The first part is true and the second part is false.

> If an element $\alpha\in k_2$ is algebraic over $k$, it is algebraic over $k_1$.

This is true because a polynomial over $k$ is a polynomial over $k_1$.

> If $\alpha$ has degree $n$ over $k$, its degree over $k_1$ divides $n$.

This is not true. Let $k = \mathbb{Q}$, $k_1 = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$,$k_2 = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}, \omega)$, where $\omega = e^{2\pi i / 3}$ as usual, and let $\alpha = \omega \sqrt[3]{2}$.
Then:

- The minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $k = \mathbb{Q}$ is $x^3 - 2$, which has degree $3$.
- The minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $k_1 = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$ is $(x/\sqrt[3]{2})^2 + (x/\sqrt[3]{2}) + 1$ (because $\omega^2 + \omega + 1 = 0$), which has degree $2$.

And you can see that $2$ does not divide $3$.

Comment: 6005, Thank you very much.

Comment: @Bolt You are welcome.

Answer (score -1):

The proposition is true.  For $\alpha$ to be algebraic over $k$, there must be a polynomial with coefficients in $k$ with $\alpha$ as a root.  Since each coefficient is also in $k_1$, the first assertion follows.  For $\alpha$ to have degree $n$ over $k$, then the dimension of $k_2$ over $k$, denoted [$k_2$ : $k$], is equal to $n$; then there is a theorem which asserts [$k_2$ : $k$] = [$k_2$ : $k_1$] [$k_1$ : $k$], and the second assertion follows.

Comment: And that theorem is the Tower Law.

Comment: But not necesserily $k_2 =k[\alpha]$. Just think of $\alpha=\sqrt{-2}$ and $\mathbb{Q},\mathbb{R},\mathbb{C}$ as fields.

Comment: It doesn't follow directly from the power law.

Comment: In fact, the result is not true, see my answer.

Comment: 6005, Thank you very much.